# Dual Boot from hard disk in windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I would like to dual boot my Windows 10 preinstalled laptop with Ubuntu from the hard disk. Can anyone help me with the procedure?

Comment: Alternatively, you could run Ubuntu in a virtual machine. Guide -  ["How to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in Virtual Box..."](http://www.beopensource.com/2016/05/how-to-install-Ubuntu-1604-LTS-in-Virtual-Box-VmWare.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's simple just make another two partitions one of them 1GB and another is for the system you may choose the preferred size of it.
Then run the graphical installer of Ubuntu's Live CD one it come to hard disk configuration to install make the 1GB sized partition a swap area and mount `/` to the other partition.
that's a short description for the whole operation.
the information that i described in this answer is the most tricky one so you should take care.
Everything else is not hard.